# Scaling a tree (forest package)

Tags: tables, scaling, trees

[image: Tree+Table]

Hello, I am trying to figure out how to scale the tree on the left because it is a little bit disproportionate compared to the table. I am looking for a code that can solve it. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: please, help us to help you! provide small but complete document with your tree which we can improve as you like to have. in generally, increase sibling and level distances.

Comment: Here's an answer (using `\scalebox{1.5}{...}` : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169136/146828

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the below suggestion works:

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.91\textwidth}
....
\end{adjustbox}
```

If this not helps, then post a `MWE` for your requirement...

Comment: Really, this should be a last resort since it will scale the fonts, too, will it not?