# Tree in slide with pause for each node

Tags: beamer, forest, trees, pause

I have a slide with some text and I want to add a tree under them.

something like the gif below.
[image]

The pause for each node is really not important but if possible, it will be much better.
and is there possible to change forest size?

I tried this code but tree exceed the page size:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Introduction}
    \begin{itemize}
        \setlength\itemsep{1em}
        \item \lipsum[1][1-5]
        \item \lipsum[1][1-5]
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{forest}
            for tree = {
                circle, 
                draw, 
                edge = {-Straight Barb, semithick},
                l sep=8mm, 
                s sep=15mm, 
                minimum size = 3em,
                EL/.style 2 args = {edge label={%
                        node[midway, font=\footnotesize, align=center,
                        inner sep=2pt, anchor=south #1]{#2}},
                },
            }
            [Outlook,
            [Humidity, EL={east}{sunny}
            [Play, EL={east}{H $\leq$ 75}]
            [Don't play, EL={west}{H > 75}]
            ]
            [Play, EL={east}{Overcast}]
            [Wind, EL={west}{Raining}
            [Play, EL={east}{weak}]
            [Don't play, EL={west}{strong}]
            ]
            ]
        \end{forest}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Have a look at the `overlay-beamer-styles` tikz library to uncover nodes step-by-step

Comment: Can you clarify what problem you face in adding the tree? From your previous question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/702890/36296 it seems like you know how to draw basic trees. What exactly is missing to reproduce the one shown in your image?

Comment: I'd suggest [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642435/best-method-to-animate-a-step-by-step-state-space-diagram-construction-in-tikz) as base concept, except for the time constraint.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I want to draw this tree in beamer and if it's possible add puase for each node otherwise resize the tree to fit it in my slide, like the gif I provide in question.

Comment: @ErfanRiahi Please show what you tried. If you can draw the tree, we can help you resize it and adding pauses.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I edit the question and add the code. as you can see tree exceed the page. In addition I really like to make all node size the same, how to do that? minimum size doesn't work.

Comment: @ErfanRiahi, as a bypass, what you always can do is to make several copies of the >>page<<, delete from the tree backwards so to say and show page after page. This gives the same visual impression.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169127/scale-of-a-forest-tree and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112471/36296

Comment: But don't put your tree in a `scalebox` as the top ranking answer to the earlier question does. The lower ranked answer is much better. Alternatively, look at options for tikz scaling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Scaling forests has been asked before at [Scale of a {forest} tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169127/scale-of-a-forest-tree)
- to pause between the nodes, you can use the solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112471/36296
- use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` if you want to actually see the `>`-signs in your document

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\forestset{
  visible on/.style={
    for tree={
      /tikz/visible on={#1},
      edge+={/tikz/visible on={#1}}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Introduction}
    \begin{itemize}
        \setlength\itemsep{1em}
        \item \lipsum[1][1-5]
        \item \lipsum[1][1-5]
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{figure}
        \scriptsize
        \begin{forest}
            for tree = {
                ellipse, 
                draw, 
                edge = {-Straight Barb, semithick},
                l sep=1.5em, 
                s sep=2.5em, 
                minimum width=6em,
                EL/.style 2 args = {edge label={%
                        node[midway, font=\tiny, align=center,
                        inner sep=2pt, anchor=south #1]{#2}},
                },
            }
            [Outlook
            [Humidity, visible on=<2->, EL={east}{sunny}
            [Play, visible on=<3->, visible on=<3->, EL={east}{H $\leq$ 75}]
            [Don't play, visible on=<4->, EL={west}{H > 75}]
            ]
            [Play, visible on=<5->, EL={east}{Overcast}]
            [Wind, visible on=<6->, EL={west}{Raining}
            [Play, visible on=<7->, EL={east}{weak}]
            [Don't play, visible on=<8->, EL={west}{strong}]
            ]
            ]
        \end{forest}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]